# Axon improperly handling merged segments

Tags: hibernate, axon

We have an application, which uses Axon Server, where we're implementing automatic scaling of instances within a k8s cluster.

The scaling code looks at the Axon Server API to determine which processors have either free thread instances or unassigned segments. If free thread instances are found then the segment is split. If a warning is seen with a message "Not all segments claimed" then the processor is merged. Once the split/merge request is done, we poll on the API to get the processor information, waiting for the tracker count to change accordingly.

When scaling up (splitting) this works fine. When scaling down (merging) we fairly often see an exception in the application logs, pertaining to the management of the tokens in the JPA token store.

The following log was 300ms after having sent the merge API request. Prior to this, 2 instances, each configured for 2 threads, were running. We'd scaled up to 4 threads total, and then I killed one instance. This left 2 segments unassigned. Hence the need to merge. We would ideally like to merge and move before an instance dies, but we do need to be able to handle unexpected instance death like this.

```
2020-06-12 14:41:51.417  INFO 14056 [:] --- [EventHandler]-0] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.TokenEntry#org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.TokenEntry$PK@9e1d11cf]

org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.TokenEntry#org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.TokenEntry$PK@9e1d11cf]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.lock.PessimisticWriteSelectLockingStrategy.lock(PessimisticWriteSelectLockingStrategy.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.lock(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1928)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractLockUpgradeEventListener.upgradeLock(AbstractLockUpgradeEventListener.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSessionCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.lockAndLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:406)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1256)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2866)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2847)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3482)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3456)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor219.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy277.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.JpaTokenStore.loadToken(JpaTokenStore.java:216)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.JpaTokenStore.storeToken(JpaTokenStore.java:111)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$MergeSegmentInstruction.runSafe(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1385)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$Instruction.lambda$null$0(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1139)
    at org.axonframework.common.transaction.TransactionManager.executeInTransaction(TransactionManager.java:47)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$Instruction.lambda$run$1(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1139)
    at org.axonframework.common.ProcessUtils.executeWithRetry(ProcessUtils.java:33)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$Instruction.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1139)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processInstructions(TrackingEventProcessor.java:332)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processingLoop(TrackingEventProcessor.java:297)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$TrackingSegmentWorker.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1161)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$WorkerLauncher.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1276)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2020-06-12 14:41:51.431 ERROR 14056 [:] --- [ault-executor-0] o.a.a.c.p.EventProcessorControlService   : Failed to merge segment [3] for processor [MyEventHandler]

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.TokenEntry#org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.TokenEntry$PK@9e1d11cf]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:632)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$Instruction.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1143)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processInstructions(TrackingEventProcessor.java:332)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processingLoop(TrackingEventProcessor.java:297)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$TrackingSegmentWorker.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1161)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$WorkerLauncher.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1276)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.TokenEntry#org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.TokenEntry$PK@9e1d11cf]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.wrapStaleStateException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3515)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3456)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor219.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy277.find(Unknown Source)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.JpaTokenStore.loadToken(JpaTokenStore.java:216)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.JpaTokenStore.storeToken(JpaTokenStore.java:111)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$MergeSegmentInstruction.runSafe(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1385)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$Instruction.lambda$null$0(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1139)
    at org.axonframework.common.transaction.TransactionManager.executeInTransaction(TransactionManager.java:47)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$Instruction.lambda$run$1(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1139)
    at org.axonframework.common.ProcessUtils.executeWithRetry(ProcessUtils.java:33)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$Instruction.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1139)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Is this the result of some misconfiguration of our JPA token store, or is there some incantation I'm missing?

Comment: This might be the result of improper API usage too. I refactored the scaling code to look directly at the TokenStore to find out what scaling is necessary, rather than trying to deduce this from the server API. As a result, a scaling up operation now takes <200ms instead of 90s, and scaling down doesn't seem to cause breakage. I suspect we ended up trying to merge invalid segments somehow, when relying on the server API. I'll leave the question here in case it turns out useful for someone.

Comment: Apparently I was a little too eager. It seems we can still trigger an `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction`, and the key seems to be to kill one of the older application instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are I believe already aware of, you have found a bug from Axon Framework's side on the matter here @ptomli.
You filed an issue on the Axon Server SE GitHub repository for this (which can be found [here](https://github.com/AxonIQ/axon-server-se/issues/135)), that further explains some additional steps.

The AxonIQ team has investigated the problem and indeed uncovered this to be an issue, which was marked under issue [#1451](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/1451) and resolved in [this](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/pull/1450) pull request.

In short, it had to do with an ordering requirement in the framework, which expected users to provide the lowest `segmentId` of the pair of segments to be merged. The fix for this is currently included in 4.4.

Upon investigation an additional issue was discovered, which didn't allow the merge operation if the segment to merge is unclaimed by any thread. This delegation process to do allow this will be resolved on Axon Server's end, for which the work is marked in issue [#136](https://github.com/AxonIQ/axon-server-se/issues/136).

Hoping this provides all the necessary info for you to proceed @ptomli, and for others to understand how this has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks Steven. Is the server issue likely to be resolved in the next release? I see there is a 4.3.5 Docker image for server-se, but maven only has 4.3.3 of the framework. Is there version drift or is this intentional?

Comment: Firstly, bug releases of framework and server do not necessarily  align. So simply put, Axon Framework has 3 bug releases, whereas Axon Server (Standard Edition) has 5.
By the way, I jumped the gun a little with stating the framework issue would be part of bug release 4.3.4. It'll still be part of 4.4 though, which is aimed to be released somewhere in July. Added sad news, I cannot give any certainty about whether this server fix will be included in the upcoming release, although I will do my best to see it through.

Comment: Update from my part @ptomli. The Axon Framework fix we did on part of your question here has been merged into version 4.3.5, which was released yesterday. Wanted to let you know so that you are able to try this out on your end.

Comment: Thanks @Steven, we'll try it out. Thanks for the speedy update